# Select a Specific UIButton with numbers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have a project who have 35 Buttons:

```
    IBOutlet UIButton *button1;
    IBOutlet UIButton *button2;
    IBOutlet UIButton *button3;
    ...
    IBOutlet UIButton *button35;
```

In my case I am creating a function that will select a number from 0-35, and I'm trying to select the button according to the number generated, as we see below:

```
int x = arc4random() % 35;

button[x].layer.borderColor = [[UIColor darkGrayColor] CGColor];
```

But the code does not work, because I believe that this is no way I can select the button, how can I work around this problem and select the button and change the border color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest assigning sequential tags to your buttons starting at some fixed offset, then using viewWithTag, to fetch the buttons as suggested in DanielM's alternative suggestion.

```
#define K_TAG_BASE 100   //BUTTON TAGS START AT 100

int tag = arc4random() % 35 + K_TAG_BASE;

NSButton aButton = [self.view viewWithTag: tag];
aButton.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor darkGrayColor] CGColor];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the tag field of each button and look up the button based on the tag:

```
int x = arc4random() % 35;
UIButton * desiredButton = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:x];
desiredButton.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor darkGrayColor] CGColor];
```

You can also use an IBOutletCollection in this situation to avoid having 35 button definitions:

```
IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray * _buttonsArray;
```

Comment: IBOutletCollection objects don't guarantee the order of the objects in the resulting array. I got bitten by this. In my initial testing the objects appeared to go into the array in the order in which I dragged them, but then on later tests the order was not preserved.

Comment: Good point. I have edited my answer to avoid misleading anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Since I see you set the buttons with outlets, I suggest you also define an `IBOutletCollection` property and use that to fetch a random button (in outlet collections the order isn't assured but you don't need that for random selection):

```
// In your class @interface
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *buttonsArray;

// In your class @implementation
-(void)selectRandomButton
{
    NSInteger randomIndex = arc4random() % self.buttonsArray.count;
    ((UIButton *)self.buttonsArray[randomIndex]).layer.borderColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor;
}
```